# Toast Notifications Not Showing Up on Nexus 7 Tablet

Tags: android, notifications, tablet, toast

I am trying to get a `Toast` notification to show up on my Nexus 7 tablet - however, they will not show.  I use custom `Toast` messages throughout most of my app, but even something as simple as:

```
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "generic toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

is not working.

I have tested this app on other devices, including a Nexus 1 phone (2.3), MyTouch (2.2), and Acer Iconia tablet (4.0).  The toast messages appear on all other devices except this Nexus 7 tablet (4.1).

Is there a user setting that allows the disabling of `Toast` notifications in an application?  Or are `Toast` messages handled differently post-4.1? These are my only ideas currently.  I've searched this problem on Google and haven't gotten a single link regarding a similar issue.

Comment: Did you try custom toast? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: I can tell you that the `Toast` displayed at the end of the `AsyncTask` in this sample project works fine on my Nexus 7: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask

Comment: Yahor10: I am using custom toasts.  I've actually followed that exact tutorial.  These don't show either.

CommonsWare: I tried showing a similar Toast at the end of one of my `AsyncTasks` - it still won't show (although I couldn't use the "getActivity()" method - I used mContext [set to "this" in the main activity] and MainActivity.this in place of that).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe [this post](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013) can help you.

Sounds like a bug.

---

**Edit**: In case the link dies, essentially:

Go to Settings -> Apps -> My_App and locate a little box labeled "Show Notifications" underneath it.  If it is unchecked, check it.

Comment: Aha!  I went to Settings -> Apps -> My app and found a little box labeled "Show Notifications" underneath it that was unchecked.  That link was quite useful.  Thank you!