# Disabling notifications also disables toast on Oreo

Tags: android

On Android O, when disabling notifications for an app, not only for specific channel (or channels) but for the whole app, all Toast messages within the app won't display anymore. Is this normal?
BTW, I'm not missing the .show() call or anything else, the same running app displays a toast even with disabling notifications for the app when running on Android < Oreo but not when running on Oreo:

`Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Does anyone knows if this is a bug or part of the changes on Oreo?
I don't see anything specific mentioning that on the [Android website](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes).

**EDIT**:

This other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625643/toast-notification-issue-with-recent-device-update-in-android) is not the same because it is asking for an alternative to Toast. I'm asking if it is a known bug or part of the Oreo changes. Seems like the correct answer is Redman's answer and the Google Issue on the Issue Tracker that he posted. It is a bug that seems to be not resolved yet. (the issue is not referenced on the other question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toast Notification issue with recent device update in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625643/toast-notification-issue-with-recent-device-update-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes ,this is normal behaviour (or a bug in android may be) .

better use `SnackBar` instead of `Toast`

Check this on Google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36951147

Comment: How do you know it is normal and not a bug? And why is the behavior different on Oreo and on previous versions?

Comment: Yes it happened to me on version 7+ too ,had to waste half a day checking what was wrong

Comment: That issue is 6 years old but looks like the problem is exactly the same. I would have think that was resolved at this point, seems like not.

Comment: @VicJordan check all comments and there dates

Comment: @Redman yes you are right there is issue with API level 26 and 27.

Answer (score 4):

I tested on 8.1 Emulator and Toast is working completely fine even after turning off notifications **IF** `compileSdkVersion 25`. There is issue if you compile your app with `API level 26 or 27`.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Environment details:**

Emulator - Pixel 2 API 27 (Android 8.1 Google APIs)

**Workaround solutions:**

1. [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar) (which is already proposed by Redman)
2. [toast-compat](https://github.com/kamikat/toast-compat) library

Comment: Useful info to know that the Toast actually displays when running with `compileSdkVersion 25 `. +1 for that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Toasts are also disabled on 9.0. It seems that it is not a bug, since users now have more specific notification settings than before.

On Android Pie 9.0, I am getting this in the log:

```
E/NotificationService: Suppressing toast from package com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx by user request.
```

Answer (score 0):

Repleace "getContext()" or anything to "getApplicationContext()". example: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`for Activity.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

for Fragment. Enjoy