# Toast not working on Samsung gt-p5110

Tags: android

What should I do to force Samsung gt-p5110 to display a standard Toast message?

```
Toast.makeText(context,"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This line of code works on many tablets and phones. I have a problem only with Samsung which does not display anything.

Comment: I'm using it.

private Context context;

and in constructor
this.context=getApplicationContext()

Comment: may be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056097/toast-notifications-not-showing-up-on-nexus-7-tablet

Comment: Yes, hahaha, that's a solution. Very funy, I would not think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug

**read this**

*Toasts are disabled if notifications are disabled for an app (Jelly Bean)*

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

it mostly happens with 7' and 10' tablets

Comment: Is there any general possibility to turn it on programmatically? Some of users of my app are not very new solutions-aware people.

Comment: I think u have 10' tablet